# Views. Can one field query multiple fields?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I created extended user profiles and I'd like to query them.

Suppose a user lives in 2 states: STATE1: New York. STATE2: California, I can easily have 2 query boxes (with views) for STATE1 and STATE2, but I'd like to have ONE query box that will ask EITHER fields.

With views, I know how to do :
If STATE1="myValue-1" OR STATE2="myValue-2"

but what I'd like to do is

If STATE1="myValue" OR STATE2="myValue"

Is this possible ?

Many thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 0):

Similar question was answered by me [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10110/combining-2-exposed-filters/10111#10111)
As I wrote, while it seems like an overhead, I couldn't find a better solution yet.
Hope this helps,
Shushu

Comment: Many thanks Shushu. Sorry for a newbie question, but where would you put the PHP code that you wrote?

Comment: Just saw your comment... First try without the autocomplete, so just create the computer field and search for it. If this works as you expected, then you will need some write some basic module to make it work. Meanwhile I will try to find my module and send it to you... Ping me if you feel I forgot it (might happen...).

Comment: Would appreciate if you sign this as an answer :-)